# DatagridView Not Updating ( Using C# Windows Application)

Tags: c#, datagridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating DataGridView using C#.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437476/updating-datagridview-using-c-net)

This is What I am trying but still not updating.

```
 con.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table_Name", con);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);
 da.Update(dt);
 dataGridview1.DataSource = null;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Also, if there is any method updating the DataGridView with SQL Query.....

Comment: how do u reject an approved edit?

Comment: @Jain ignore my comment, its mod material. Generally you bind a `DataGirdView` to a business object datasource, eg `List<Thing>()`. You can put the logic in the GIU but I wouldn't recommend that. We need more info

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code to see if the DatTable is actually populating with data when the Data Adapter attempts to Fill the Datatable.

In this instance you should be using a Binding Source. This will ensure that any changes you make to the Data Table reflect into the DataGridView Object.

You dont need to call the Update() on the Data Adapter, only the Fill() is suffice.

```
 Public BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
 Public DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table_Name", con);

 Con.Open();

 da.Fill(dt);

 Con.Close();

 bs.DataSource = dt;

 dataGridview1.DataSource = bs;
```

Doing this allows you to filter / query the DataTable in Memory, and it will reflect changes in the datagridView instantly.

Its not good practice to query the database if your query can be accomplished in the Data Table.

Answer (score -2):

Try the below code

```
con.Open();  
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table_Name", con);  
Dataset ds = new Dataset();   //changed code from datatable to dataset
da.Fill(ds);  
da.Update(ds);  
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataBind(); //databinding done here. this is missing in your code
```

Comment: I think this is winform so `DataBind()` (Anyway its a method and not property) won't fit in here

Comment: -1 bold assumption. Its not `Binding` its `Updating`.

Comment: @jeremy Thompson. its NOT updating, its re-binding the data to the grid with new datatabel values.